# SSIS: ODBC Connection Issue in BIDS 2008

Tags: oracle, ssis, odbc, bids

I have an oracle DB i need to talk to so i installed the drivers and added it to the system DSN Data Sources.   IM ON SQL SERVER 2008 R2 64bit

In BIDS, I can see the name of the DataSource, however when i go to enter it in the connection manager I get the following error:

### TITLE: Connection Manager

Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Any Ideas on how to resolve this?

I can connect to the Oracle DB through SQL Plus so i know i have connectivity.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of the oracle drivers did you install?

Comment: OraClient11g...idk if that is what you are looking for?

Comment: FWIW I've had lots of issues with SSIS and ODBC to Oracle (and that's not even accounting that your using x64).  I decided to use ODP.NET & OLE DB instead and haven't looked back.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed the 11g client, I assume you did a custom install and installed the ODBC driver, right? And you set your ODBC DSN up using the Oracle Driver, not the Microsoft Driver? Did you test the DSN with the ODBC wizard?

Comment: Yes, I tested it w/ success. The problem is that it does not recognize the system DSN in BIDS.  I can access the oracle db through sql plus and I can succussfuly test the conection in the ODBC Manager...

Answer (score 0):

@kevin

The Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

this error can be resolved by using a 32 bit driver for oracle connectivity and setting the package runtime properties to set 64 bit runtime= false.

also create a odbc dsn by using the 32 bit oracle driver.on 64 bit machines search for odbc32.exe. the path for it is the following C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe.
run this as an administrator and use this DSN in your SSIS package and the issue will be resolved.